# Are there any extensive library for android icons

Tags: android

Is there a library for icons in Android such as font awesome is in web development and how is it used?

Comment: For the font check this video [Using Fonts in Android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TfB-TsLFJdM)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. From material.io you can use it's icon library:
   https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline
2. Right click on `res\drawable` resource folder and select `New\Vector Asset` to add vector icons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below library for Icons It will mostly use font-awesome icons.

[Here is font icon library for native android click here for more detail](https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics)

Import library from above link and used like below.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    app:ico_color="@color/md_red_A200"
    app:ico_icon="gmd-plus-circle" // or @string/gmd_plus_circle with our generator
    app:ico_size="48dp" />
```